# RestKit 0.10 Object Mapping with JSON for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, mapping, restkit

I've spent many hours reading the documentation and tried out various sample projects etc. but I just can't solve my problems. As Restkit changed many APIs a few days ago much of the information provided and the tutorials is useless. The stuff that works does not help me with my problems.

In General, I don't understand when to use /person or /person.user or /:user or /person/user when doing the object mapping. I havent found anything about how to access certain JSON entries. Mybe someone can explain this to me.

I want to create objects out of my JSON Response. The Problem is using objects or arrays, nested in an object.

Here is the JSON that causes problems:

```
{
   "result":
   {
       "persons":
       [
           {
               "age": 20,
               "name": "alice",
               "user":
               {
                   "id": 208727870
               }
            },
            {
               "age": 25,
               "name": "bob",
               "user":
               {
                   "id": 308427890
               }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For this sample I need to do the object mapping -> but how?

This mapping works:

```
{
   "result":
   [
       {
           "age": 20,
           "name": "alice",
           "user":
           {
               "id": 208727870
           }
        },
        {
           "age": 25,
           "name": "bob",
           "user":
           {
               "id": 308427890
           }
        }
    ]
}

RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKTUser class]];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"userID"];

RKObjectMapping* statusMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKTStatus class]];
[statusMapping mapKeyPath:@"age" toAttribute:@"age"]
[statusMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]

[statusMapping mapRelationship:@"user" withMapping:userMapping];
statusMapping.rootKeyPath = @"result";

// user seems only to be a placeholder .. it does not matter, which string i write instead "user"
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:statusMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/:user"];
```

What I finally want to do:

```
{
   "result":
   {
       "id_str": "208727870",
       "result_value_str": "123456",
       "persons":
       [
           {
               "age": 20,
               "name": "alice",
               "user":
               {
                   "id": 208727870
               }
            },
            {
               "age": 25,
               "name": "bob",
               "user":
               {
                   "id": 308427890
               }
            }
        ],
        "friends":
       [
           {
               "age": 18,
               "name": "norton",
               "user":
               {
                   "id": 208457120
               }
            },
            {
               "age": 41,
               "name": "edward",
               "user":
               {
                   "id": 378829810
               }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Has someone an advice for me? (tutorials, links, hints…)

Best regards,
Steve